# Forward declaration and circular dependencies in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a simple relationship in C++. It goes like this:

- teleport changes objects location from one lane to another
- lane holds some other objects as well as multiple teleports.
  This presents a circular dependencies problem, that I can't solve.
  I am already using forward declarations and I have no idea what to do next.

Lane.h

```
#include "Teleport.h"
    class Lane
    {
    public:
        std::map<long long, object> object_container;
        std::map<long long, Teleport> teleports_container;

        void add_Object(///) { object_container.emplace(//object//); }
        void add_Teleport(const Teleport &t) { teleport_container.emplace(t._uid, t); }

        Object &get_Object(long long uid) { return object_container.at(uid); }
        Teleport &get_Teleport(long long uid) { return teleports_container.at(uid); }
    }
```

Teleport.cpp

```
#include "Lane.h"
#include "Teleport.h"

    void Teleport::teleport_Object(long long tp_uid)
    {
        _destination.add_Object(_origin.get_Object(tp_uid));
    }
}
```

Teleport.h

```
  class Lane;

  class  Teleport
   {
    public:
        const Lane &_origin;
        const Lane &_destination;

        Teleport(const Lane &origin, const Lane &destination)
            : _origin{origin}, _destination{destination}{}

        void teleport_Object(long long tp_uid);
    };
```

Compile error for Teleport.cpp " error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘const class Lane’"
Would appreciate any help.

Comment: _destination is a reference to a const, add_Object is impossible. The declaration of the class Lane without a semicolon is incomplete.

Comment: Seems like teleport_Object should be a function that the object has (i.e. `_origin.get_Object(tp_uid).teleport_Object(...)` where you give it the destination lane, and then it removes it from the origin and adds it to the destination lanes.  Not sure what Teleport as an object gets you here.

Comment: So, in short, a `Teleport` contains two `Lane` which themselves contain maps of `Teleport`, each containing two `Lane`, which contain maps of `Teleport`... etc? I maybe overlooking something, but I don't think your real problem here is circular dependencies.

Comment: Martin, Teleport contains references to Lanes, not objects themselves

Comment: SM, those errors are due to me anonymizing my code. That const is an error, but I think it is not responsible for this exact error code.

Comment: Syntheticgio, I want my objects to be limited by how they can teleport. Each teleport has source and destination and by being connected to the lane, it makes sure that objects can move only by designed path and not how they wish. If objects would move by themselves, there would be no way of me controlling, if they use only existing connections.